# How can I produce matrixes automatically in Python?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I have

```
x = np.linspace(0, 1, 6)
y = np.linspace(0, 1, 9)
```

How can I have a matrix 7x10 from (x,y) but each row becomes from the previous one by adding 1? For example, the first row is

0,1,2,3,4,5,6

the second row

1,2,3,4,5,6,7

and so on

Answer (score 3):

With [broadcasting](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html) in numpy:

```
x = np.arange(7)
y = np.arange(10)

x[np.newaxis, :] + y[:, np.newaxis]
```

Output:

```
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6],
       [ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8],
       [ 3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11],
       [ 6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12],
       [ 7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
       [ 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]])
```

Or the same thing with [`np.reshape`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html):

```
x.reshape(1, -1) + y.reshape(-1, 1)
```

And here's possibly a little more readable, but significantly less computationally efficient:

```
m = np.empty((10, 7))
for i in range(10):
    for j in range(7):
        m[i, j] = i + j
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, but due to I have started to learn Python I don't want just to use commands I want to create them if you know what I mean. I want to write a code to do the calculations

Comment: @AggelosVassilakos Hm, no I don't think I quite understand what you're trying to achieve then. Maybe you can try rephrasing the question if you're looking for a different kind of solution...

Comment: I want exactly the output that you gave me, but in a different way, you know more mathematical for instance by using a for loop with x or y or something like that

Comment: OK, I've added the one with the loops, but please be aware that it is much less efficient. In general, whenever you can avoid using explicit loops by using vectorized numpy functions instead, you should always do that, as it's normally much faster

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. You know I have started to learn Python for about 3 months and I want to understand the Philosophy, I am not very good at coding as a rookie that's why I am pushing my self and when I cannot find the solution, StackOverflow is here :)